# How to change space between rows in FlexboxLayoutManager?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, flexbox, linearlayoutmanager

I'm using FlexboxLayoutManager.

How to change space between rows, and space between items on the first row?
[image]

```
class FlexboxLayoutManagerImpl(context: Context, flexDirection: Int) :
    FlexboxLayoutManager(context, flexDirection) {

    override fun generateLayoutParams(lp: ViewGroup.LayoutParams): RecyclerView.LayoutParams {
        return LayoutParams(lp)
    }
}
```

And call from my adapter:

```
contentParent.getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(v1 -> {
     FlexboxLayoutManagerImpl flexboxLayoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManagerImpl(context, FlexDirection.ROW);
     holder.recycleListView.setLayoutManager(flexboxLayoutManager);
});
```

Comment: Is that change your RecycleView holder view margin complex requirements?

Comment: layout_marginTop only apples space on recycleview top, not between rows

Comment: I found the solution. For space between items I made separate recycleview and special adapter, but for space between rows, it was top margin of cardview.